# UPDATE column from another column two tables away

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Not that good with SQL yet but I'm learning.

So I have 3 tables:

tblOne(Id, Type)
tblTemp1(Name, Type)
tblTemp2(Id, Name)

Basically, I want to update tblOne where the where it's 'Id' matches from tblTemp2, but than that also goes and grabs its 'Type' from tblTemp1 where the 'Name' matches.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using joins in your update statement.

```
UPDATE tblOne 
SET tblOne.Type = tblTemp1.Type
FROM tblTemp2
INNER JOIN tblTemp1 ON tblTemp1.Name = tblTemp2.Name
WHERE tblOne.Id = tblTemp2.Id
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: Is this syntax correct?  I've never seen a JOIN performed before a set?  (Not picking holes, just never seen this before)

Comment: You're right. This is a MySQL-specific syntax. I've edited the post to use the Sql Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tblOne
SET
tblOne.Type = tblTemp1.Type
WHERE
tblOne.Id = tblTemp2.Id
AND
tblTemp1.Name = tblTemp2.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TBLONE 
SET    TBLONE.TYPE = (SELECT TBLTEMP1.TYPE 
                      FROM   TBLTEMP1 
                             INNER JOIN TBLTEMP2 
                                     ON TBLTEMP1.NAME = TBLTEMP2.NAME 
                      WHERE  TBLONE.ID = TBLTEMP2.ID);
```

Ff we need to update only satisfies a condition
Then add this part for that statement
and where condition//where clause is optional